have a 52" geared table extension.table, top 48" wide and 2 - 24" table leaf's. How do I modify the extension to add the 2 leaves?
52" geared table extension. Table top is 48". Have 2 24" leafs. How can I modify the 52" extension to accommodate the both 24" extensions?

Welcome to WSE.  It is not clear exactly what is going on.  Is 52" the opening on the table?  If so, what prevents the leaves from fitting? In order to answer your question, we will need a lot more information. Please tell us more about the table including approx. how old it is and manufacturer if known (is it modern or an antique?).  We will also need pictures of the table in the open position & a leaf showing the gear system and underside.
